# Question on Morera's theorem proof

Tags: complex-analysis

I am trying to understand this proof and I am having trouble understanding a couple things.

2) How do we know that F is analytic?

3) Is it necessary to say the things about primitives?

3) How do we know that $F'=f$? Maybe I am remembering incorrectly, but for some reason I thought the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus didn't apply for complex analysis...

Thanks!

[image]

Comment: By definition, a primitive of $f$ is an analytic function $F$ such that $F'(z) = f(z)$.  So (2) yes.  (1) and (3) you have to prove that, hopefully it's proved in one of the links.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$\frac {F(z+h)-F(z)} h = \frac {\int_{[z,z+h]} f(w) \, dw} h =\frac {\int_{[z,z+h]} [f(w)-f(z)] \, dw} h +f(z) \to f(z)$$ as $ h  \to 0$ by continuity of $f$. [ The first equation follows by considering three paths: one from $z_0$ to $z+h$, one from  $z_0$ to $z+h$ and the line segment from $z$ to $z+h$. Drawing a picture helps]. It follows that $f$ is differentiable at all points of $D$ with $F'(z)=f(z)$. The derivative of any analytic functions is also analytic. [This can be proved using power series expansions]. Hence $f$ is analytic.